# svelte app deployed with github-pages show blank page on first time

Tags: github-pages, svelte

I couldn't determine why this happened, So I ask my question.
I got some svelte app deployed by github pages.(https://raina94.github.io/kalimba-sheet-generator/)
The problem is, When I enter my app, There are only blank page.
The only way to see my app is pressing ctrl+shift+R (cache clear).

I really want to know reason that occur blank pages.
you can see all my sources into https://github.com/raina94/kalimba-sheet-generator.

Thank you for your helping.
Is there anything you want to know more, Just let me know.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce when I checked your page, it's displayed correctly. Check the browser console when the issue occurs to see if there are errors.

Comment: thanks your comment! I realized, when read your comment ,that my app is not just blank page, but can not clear browser cache. I.. should find the way clear cache after deployed my app. Anyway, Thanks again!